# Angular: How can I get target inside proxy.conf.js and use it inside a component?

Tags: javascript, angular

My proxy.conf.js in my angular-project looks like this:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/api"
    ],
    target: "https://localhost:1234",
    secure: false
  }
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

In a component, I want to display that target path. For example:

```
<p>
Target as specified in proxy.conf.js: 
{{ myTarget }} // <-- this should display "https://localhost:1234"
</p>
```

How can I do this?

**ng version**: Angular: 15.2.6